# How to restore firebird database using .net FbRestore?

Tags: .net, firebird, database-restore

I have database backup which I want to restore to database, but when I run example code:

```
FbRestore restoreSvc = new FbRestore();
restoreSvc.ConnectionString = "...";
restoreSvc.BackupFiles.Add(new FbBackupFile(dumpFileName, 2048));
restoreSvc.PageSize = 4096;
restoreSvc.Options = FbRestoreFlags.Create | FbRestoreFlags.Replace;
restoreSvc.Execute();
```

it ends throwing exception

```
could not drop database ...db path... (database might be in use)
   at FirebirdSql.Data.Services.FbRestore.Execute()
```

By default there are other applications using the database, but if I stop all of them, nothing is changed.

How can I restore database in such environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the database can be dropped. That means nobody is currently using it.

If it's only your application you should close all connections (really close, be aware of connection pooling) and then do the restore. Or if there are also other connections you can i.e. *forcibly* close these connections by doing `DELETE FROM MON$ATTACHMENTS WHERE MON$ATTACHMENT_ID <> CURRENT_CONNECTION`.

Comment: I want to delete backup file after restore, but FbRestore doesn't implement IDisposable. How can I release the file after restore? I am getting 'file is used' exception if I will try to delete it.

Comment: FbRestore is not touching the file, it's using ServicesAPI. Server is opening the file. So you have to wait before the restore is completed, then the server releases the file.

Answer (score 1):

Before use FbRestore need to call FbConnection.ClearAllPools()